# jQuery validate , how to make validation rules for dynamically generated fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML form with dynamically add more fields. For example company name. I am trying to use the jQuery validate method to validate. It is working fine with the existing company name field. Here is the code.

```
<script>
     $("#company_creation_form").validate({ 
            rules:{
                company_name: { 
                    required: true, 
                    minlength: 3 
                }

            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "<?php echo BASE_URL;?>crm/thankyou/",
                 data: $(form).serialize()+"&company_count="+company_count,
                 success: function () {
                     alert("thanks");                     
                 }
             });
             return false; // required to block normal submit since you used ajax
         }
     });
</script>
```

When I click on add more button another company name field will create on the form. The below code is failed to validate the dynamically generated field. Here I am getting the field count globally in this variable `company_count`

```
<script>
     $("#company_creation_form").validate({ 
            rules:{
                company_name: { 
                    required: true, 
                    minlength: 3 
                },
```

`I tried like below, but this is giving me error`

```
            if(company_count> 0){
                var new_field = jQuery("#company_name"+company_count);
                new_field : { 
                                required: true, 
                                minlength: 3 
                            },
                        }
```

`The above block code is showing error in the text editor it self`

```
},
submitHandler: function (form) {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "<?php echo BASE_URL;?>crm/thankyou/",
                 data: $(form).serialize()+"&company_count="+company_count,
                 success: function () {
                     alert("thanks");                     
                 }
             });
          return false; // required to block normal submit since you used ajax
         }
     });
</script>
```

Can anyone help me with how to make validation for these dynamically generated fields? Any help would be greatly appreciated.  `I am using form submission by using Ajax`.
`Code to add company fields dynamically`

```
var company_room = 0;
var company_room1 = 0;
function add_another_company() {
    company_room++;
    company_room1++;
    var objTo = document.getElementById('company_field')
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass2" + company_room);
    //var rdiv = 'removeclass2' + company_room;
    divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="form-row"><div class="col-sm-5"> <div class="form-group pad-tp-5"><input type="text" class="form-control aj4" id="company_name" name="company_name" placeholder="Company Name"></div></div><div class="col-sm-2"> <div class="form-group"> <button class="btn btn-danger bdr-rds-100 btn-pad" type="button" onclick="remove_another_company(' + company_room + ');"> <i class="fa fa-minus"></i> </button> </div></div></div>';

    objTo.appendChild(divtest);
    var E_fields = $('.aj4');
    var E_count = 1;
    $.each(E_fields, function() {
        jQuery(this).attr('id','company_name' + E_count);
        jQuery(this).attr('name','company_name' + E_count);
        E_count++;
    });
}

function remove_another_company(rid2) {
        company_room1--;
        $('.removeclass2' + rid2).remove();
        var E_fields = $('.aj4');
        var E_count = 1;
        $.each(E_fields, function() {
            jQuery(this).attr('id','company_name' + E_count);
            jQuery(this).attr('name','company_name' + E_count);
            E_count++;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I didn't have your HTML so I had to mock some up.   You will obviously have to tweak this a little to work with your ID's.  I tried to keep it as close as possible to the ID's/classes you were already using.

I removed the pure javascript functions and the onclick events in favor of jquery since you were already using it.  Hopefully this kind of simplifies things a bit and makes it more manageable.

NOTE: I added a hidden input field to keep track of company count.  This way it will be included when you $(form).serialize in your ajax options (as you are adding it with a variable now).   I included code to preserve the company_count variable also, so basically you will have 2 company counts.  I did this just to show you an easier way to keep track of this without having to micro manage it.  :)

Try out this code and let me know what your getting in console if it is not working.   Thanks

MOCK HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form-wrapper">
  <p>Dynamic Form</p>
  <button id="addField">Add Dynamic Field</button>
  <form id="dynForm">
    Static Field: <input id="company_name" name="company_name" minlength="3" type="text" value="Static Company Name" required>
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" id="companyCount" name="companyCount" value="1">
    <div id="company_field">

    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

JQUERY/JS

```
$(function() {  // <---- Document Ready!
  $("#addField").on("click", () => {
    var count = parseInt($("#companyCount").val(), 10);
    count += 1;
    $("#companyCount").val(count.toString());
    var thisId = "company_name" + count.toString();
    var html = '<div class="form-row"><div class="col-sm-5"> <div class="form-group pad-tp-5"><input type="text" class="form-control aj4" id="'+thisId+'" name="'+thisId+'" minlength="3" placeholder="Company Name" required></div></div><div class="col-sm-2"> <div class="form-group"> <button class="btn btn-danger bdr-rds-100 btn-pad" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-minus"></i> </button> </div></div></div>';
    var ele = $.parseHTML(html);

    $("#company_field").append(ele);

  });

  $("#company_field").on("click", "button", () => $(this).closest(".form-row").remove());


    $("#company_creation_form").validate({
      submitHandler: function(form) {
        var company_count = parseInt($("#companyCount").val(), 10);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<?php echo BASE_URL;?>crm/thankyou/",
          data: $(form).serialize() + "&company_count=" + company_count,
          success: function() {
            alert("thanks");
          }
        });
        return false; 
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you please show me a bit more above with my code? Because I am bit new to this functionality. Many thanks in advance

Comment: I have updated question with add more company fields.

Comment: @ Brian Patterson, did you get a chance to look into this?

Comment: @user3408779 Apologies, I had to hit the rack for some shut-eye.  I am taking a look now.   Can you post the HTML so I can set up a snippet/fiddle?

Comment: thank you very much for your effort. But validation is asking only for first field. And another thing is I need to save the company name values in db. So company name should be increment like company_name1, company_name2 etc...(based on the company field count I am iterating loop and insert values in db )

Comment: @user3408779 OK, so I updated the code a bit.   Can you try it and see if the validation is working.   The only issue is that the company count will be off but you can work around it in your server side script or I can create a workaround in the javascript if you need to.  But first check this code out and let me know how it goes.   NOTE:  validation rules added to the HTML `minlength="3"` and `required` added to the `input` elements.

Comment: thank you... The Validation part is working. But when I click on the submit button, the page is submitting directly without performing ajax call.

Comment: @user3408779 Make sure your submit button is set to `type="submit"` Can you post the HTML for your form?